# Which CSS selector is faster: ul > li:nth-of-type(3) > a .. or ul > li > a:nth-of-type(3)

Tags: jquery, html, css, optimization

Suppose I have a list like

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>List item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>List item 2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>List item 3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>List item 4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Then the selectors `ul > li:nth-of-type(3) > a` and `ul > li > a:nth-of-type(3)` target the same element. But which one is faster on average? And why?

In general, if you have something like

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>List item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>List item 2</a>
  </li>
  .
  .
  .
  <li>
    <a>List item k</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and need to select `ul > li:nth-of-type(i) > a` for some `i` in the range `[1, k]`, is it faster to use `ul > li > a:nth-of-type(i)`???

Comment: I'd suggest usinga large data set, say a thousand or so elements, and running both selectors through `document.querySelectorAll()` in [JS Perf](http://jsperf.com/). Then you'll know (why it probably doesn't matter).

Comment: `ul > li:nth-of-type(3) > a and ul > li > a:nth-of-type(3) target the same element` no they don't

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in a comment, those selectors do not select the same.

A little jquery fiddle will show the difference http://jsfiddle.net/7pz402te/

So it in fact, a:nth-of-type() will be much faster, since there's only one link in your li.

```css
ul > li:nth-of-type(3) > a {
  font-size: 40px;
}
ul > li > a:nth-of-type(3) {
  color: magenta;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>List item 1.1</a>
    <a>List item 1.2</a>
    <a>List item 1.3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>List item 2.1</a>
    <a>List item 2.2</a>
    <a>List item 2.3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>List item 3.1</a>
    <a>List item 3.2</a>
    <a>List item 3.3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>List item 4.1</a>
    <a>List item 4.2</a>
    <a>List item 4.3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```